# Separate page numbering for multi page environments with total pages counts for each

Tags: packages, counters, count, totalcount

A document which I try to typeset with LaTeX may contain multi page environments.
Such environment has his own page numeration which starting from 1. But it has to be
total environment pages number at the first page of environment. I know how to do it while
there is a single environment is in document. But there is issue when I use more than 
one environment in a document with different pages amount. I know why this happens 
(those environments use one counter). How can I change this in case that the environments
amount in the document isn't known in advance?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{ccnt}%current page counter    
\newcounter{fcnt}%first page counter
\newtotcounter{tcnt}%total page counter

\newenvironment{elementlist}%
  {\clearpage
   \pagestyle{empty}
   \Environmenttrue
   \FirstBackgroundtrue
   \AddToShipoutPicture{\Background}
   \linespread{2}\selectfont
   \enlargethispage{-3\baselineskip}
   \sffamily\slshape\selectfont
   \setcounter{fcnt}{\thepage}}
  {\setcounter{tcnt}{\value{page}-\value{fcnt}+1}
   \clearpage
   \ClearShipoutPicture
   \pagestyle{plain}}

\newif\ifEnvironment
\newif\ifFirstBackground

\newcommand\Background
  {\ifFirstBackground
     \formfirst
     \global\FirstBackgroundfalse
   \else
     \formposterior
   \fi
  }

\newcommand\formfirst{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \setcounter{ccnt}{\value{page}-\value{fcnt}+1}
  \ifEnvironment
    \draw (2.0, 1.5) node[align=center,text width=4.5cm] {\total{tcnt}};
    \draw (19.5, 1.5) node[align=center,text width=4.5cm] {\arabic{ccnt}};
  \fi
 \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand\formposterior{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \setcounter{ccnt}{\value{page}-\value{fcnt}+1}
  \ifEnvironment
    \draw (19.5, 1.5) node[align=center,text width=4.5cm] {\arabic{ccnt}};
  \fi
 \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext

 \begin{elementlist}
 \Blindtext
 \end{elementlist}

\Blindtext 

 \begin{elementlist}
 \Blindtext
 \Blindtext
\end{elementlist}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xcntperchap` and track the number of pages for each environment.

Later on, call `\ObtainTrackedValueExp{elistcntr}{page}`, which extracts the number of pages first.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{elistcntr}

\newcounter{ccnt}%current page counter    
\newcounter{fcnt}%first page counter
\newtotcounter{tcnt}%total page counter

\usepackage{xcntperchap}


\RegisterTrackCounter{elistcntr}{page}




\newenvironment{elementlist}{%
  \clearpage
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \Environmenttrue
  \FirstBackgroundtrue
  \refstepcounter{elistcntr}%
  \clearpage
  \AddToShipoutPicture{\Background}
  \linespread{2}\selectfont
  \enlargethispage{-3\baselineskip}
  \sffamily\slshape\selectfont
  \setcounter{fcnt}{\thepage}
}{%
  \setcounter{tcnt}{\value{page}-\value{fcnt}+1}
  \clearpage%
  \refstepcounter{elistcntr}%
  \ClearShipoutPicture
  \pagestyle{plain}%
  \clearpage
}

\newif\ifEnvironment
\newif\ifFirstBackground

\newcommand\Background
  {\ifFirstBackground
     \formfirst
     \global\FirstBackgroundfalse
   \else
     \formposterior
   \fi
  }

\newcommand\formfirst{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \setcounter{ccnt}{\value{page}-\value{fcnt}+1}
  \ifEnvironment
    \draw (2.0, 1.5) node[align=center,text width=4.5cm] {\ObtainTrackedValueExp{elistcntr}{page}};
    \draw (19.5, 1.5) node[align=center,text width=4.5cm] {\arabic{ccnt}};
  \fi
 \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand\formposterior{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \setcounter{ccnt}{\value{page}-\value{fcnt}+1}
  \ifEnvironment
  \draw (19.5, 1.5) node[align=center,text width=4.5cm] {\arabic{ccnt}};
  \fi
 \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext

\begin{elementlist}
  \Blindtext
\end{elementlist}

\Blindtext 

\begin{elementlist}
  \Blindtext
  \Blindtext
  \Blindtext
  \Blindtext
\end{elementlist}

\Blindtext 

\begin{elementlist}
  \Blindtext
  \Blindtext
  \Blindtext
  \Blindtext
\end{elementlist}

\Blindtext

\begin{elementlist}
  \Blindtext
  \Blindtext
  \Blindtext
  \Blindtext
  \Blindtext
  \Blindtext
  \Blindtext
  \Blindtext
\end{elementlist}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in your example in second environment I counted 9 pages, while LaTeX with `xcntperchap` typed 10.

Comment: @Konstantin: Yes. As I said, `page` is very unreliable... I'll try to improve the code

Comment: @Konstantin: see the update, please

Comment: Well, now environment pages amount typed right, but page before environment without number.

Comment: @Konstantin: Sigh... I hate the page counter. See now, please

Comment: Last variant works as it should do. It hard to find difference between code variants. Can you tell what has changed since last code?

Comment: Does this multipage environment start and end with a new page?  Otherwise there may be confusion as to which page belongs to which counter.

Comment: @Konstantin: Basically, it is the correct order of pagestyle setting and clearpage.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: It **should** start and end with a new page, of course... otherwise the whole issue is not well-defined

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Your turn....

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Can't found how can I write privately so wrote here. Hope this post will found their addressee. Thanks, with your help I did what I wanted. I use MiKTeX basically and I had no problem with `xcntperchap`. But when I tried typeset my document under Linux with TeXLive he said he can't find `xcntperchap.sty`. I have TeXLive-full installed.

Comment: @Konstantin: I assume you have one of those Linux TeXLive - distribution packages installed, that are pretty outdated in many cases. I've uploaded v0.5 two days ago and it was shipped on CTAN almost immediately, and this morning my daily update with tlmgr installed v0.5 on my TeXLive tree.